# Godot 3.5.1 No se como arreglar el problema e intentado y no me funciona ninguna que e probado

Tags: godot-engine

elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):

error(25,2): Error parsing expression, misplaced: elif

[image: Eso es lo que me sale]

Comment: Bienvenido. El código va como texto. No cuesta nada copiar y pegarlo. Cuando obtienes un error e información sobre la línea en la que está el problema, no olvides agregarlos a la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Qué tienes antes del `elif`?